# Is there a way to save the value got asignned to the movies variable in the injectdb() to use it in the getMovies()

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

The movies variable doesn't save the value assigned to it when function injectdb() is call to use in function getMovies()

So to put it in a simple way, when i run the code the function injectDB() will be called by another file from the start, and when an event trigger the getMovies() will be called later. The problem is it seems like the movies variable that i declared globally doesn't save the value assigned to it when function injectdb() is call to use in function getMovies() And i already check when i use the movies variable in the injectDB() it still run good but when the getMovies() use it, it is undefined. Is there anyway i can save the value that assigned to movies in the injectdb() function and use it in the getMovies() function.

Here is my code:

```
let movies;

export default class MoviesDAO {
  static async injectDB(conn) {
    if (movies) {
      return;
    }
    try {
      movies = await conn.db(process.env.MOVIEREVIEWS_NS).collection("movies");
      movies.find({ '$text': { '$search': 'dragon' } }).toArray()
    } catch (e) {
      console.error("unable to connect in MoviesDAO:${e}");
    }
  }


static async getMovies({// default filter
    filters = null,
    page = 0,
    moviesPerPage = 20, // will only get 20 movies at once
    } = {}){
    let query;
    if(filters){
    if("title" in filters){
    query = { $text: { $search: filters['title']}}
    console.log(query)
    }else if("rated" in filters){
    query = {"rated": { $eq: filters['rated']}}
    console.log('hello')
    }
    }
    let cursor;
    console.log(movies)
    try{
    cursor = await movies.find(query);
    const moviesList = await cursor.toArray();
    const totalNumMovies = await movies.countDocuments(query);
    return {moviesList, totalNumMovies};
    }
    catch(e){
    console.error(`Unable to issue find command, ${e}`);
    return {moviesList:[], totalNumMovies: 0};
    }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hi, take a look here: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7353417)

Comment: Can you post the code where you are calling the `injectDB` and `getMovies` functions? What's the purpose of `movies.find({ $text: { $search: 'dragon' } }).toArray();`?

Comment: here is the link to the project: https://github.com/Zuylele-II/movies_reviews i will use the command nodemon server to start a server and when i search the url "http://localhost:3000/api/v1/movies" the database will be print out. And the purpose of movies.find({ $text: { $search: 'dragon' } }).toArray(); is to test if i can get the data when the injectdb() function is call and it does return the data i need but the getMovies() function doesnt.